# How to do the conditional order by with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

i am fetching data from xml file using linq. this is my code.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\tridip\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Orders.xml");
            var books = from r in document.Descendants("Orders")
            .Skip(0)
            .Take(5)
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };

          dataGridView1.DataSource=  books.ToList().OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID);
```

the moment i add this line `.OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID);` then no data is showing through datagridview.

so my question is can't we add OrderBy this way `books.ToList().OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID);` ?

my second question is how to do order by conditionally ?

i will send a argument to my function some time like `ASC` or some time `DESC` if i send `ASC` then sorting will be done by ascending order or some time sorting will be done by descending order.

so guide me how to write code which will sort my data some time ascending or some time descending order. thanks

Comment: books.ToList().OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID) will cause two enumerations: immediate one for ToList() and a lazy one for OrderBy(). You should be able to get an ordered list by books.OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID).ToList();

Comment: Do you really want to sort your data source or just want to view it in a sorted order. If it's the latter case maybe using ICollectionView is a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
books.ToList().OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID)
```

will cause two enumerations: immediate one for ToList() and a lazy one for OrderBy(). You should be able to get an ordered list by:

```
books.OrderBy(a=> a.OrderID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional ordering is simple as 'books' will be an implementation of 'IQueryable' until you actually enumerate it. Therefore you can do this:

```
if (true)
    books = books.OrderBy();

var results = books.ToList();
```